# Is it possible to register a callback function to waitUntilDBInstanceAvailable()?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, rds

I'm using the AWS SDK for PHP, and have a command-line tool waiting for a DB instance to be created with [waitUntilDBInstanceAvailable()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.Rds.RdsClient.html#_waitUntilDBInstanceAvailable):

```php
$this->rdsClient->waitUntilDBInstanceAvailable([
    'DBInstanceIdentifier' => 'test'
]);
```

**Is there a way to register a callback function, so that every time the SDK polls RDS, my callback function is called?**

Something like:

```php
$this->rdsClient->waitUntilDBInstanceAvailable([
    'DBInstanceIdentifier' => 'test',
    'CallbackFunction'     => function() {
        echo '.';
    }
]);
```

That would give the user some feedback about the fact that the script is still waiting, and did not hang arbitrarily.

The doc says:

> The input array uses the parameters of the DescribeDBInstances operation and waiter specific settings

But I couldn't find out what these *waiter specific settings* are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [page specifically about waiters in the AWS SDK for PHP User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/feature-waiters.html). On that page it talks about how use event listeners with waiters. You need to interact directly with the waiter object.

```
// Get and configure the waiter object
$waiter = $client->getWaiter('BucketExists')
    ->setConfig(array('Bucket' => 'my-bucket'))
    ->setInterval(10)
    ->setMaxAttempts(3);

// Get the event dispatcher and register listeners for both events emitted by the waiter
$dispatcher = $waiter->getEventDispatcher();
$dispatcher->addListener('waiter.before_attempt', function () {
    echo "Checking if the wait condition has been met…\n";
});
$dispatcher->addListener('waiter.before_wait', function () use ($waiter) {
    $interval = $waiter->getInterval();
    echo "Sleeping for {$interval} seconds…\n";
});

$waiter->wait();

// Also Licensed under version 2.0 of the Apache License.
```

Comment: I have seen that, but this looked overly complicated, and I finally implemented a custom waiting function that calls `describeDBInstances` in a loop with 5s sleeps in between every attempt, and calls my callback function. It's a pity that it's actually less code than the above :) Thanks anyway for the pointer, Jeremy!

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you're looking for by implementing a [custom waiter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/feature-waiters.html). Unfortunately, it's not as simple as supporting a callback on an existing waiter, but you can still implement what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, what about adding a configuration entry for a callback function, to be able to use `waitUntilDBInstanceAvailable` directly, without further complexity?

Comment: Good idea! Done. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/commit/7d4d3e5315a90e4c461062297381284d45f6310c