# Using aws php sdk's waitUntilDBInstanceAvailable()

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, rds, aws-sdk

I'm trying to use the waitUntilDBInstanceAvailable() to wait for my newly created instance to be available so that I can grab the endpoint name.

Note: The endpoint name is not available until the instance is fully up.

I've looked at waiters but it uses different methods params, waitUntilDBInstanceAvailable takes 1 array as an argument per [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Rds.RdsClient.html#_waitUntilDBInstanceAvailable).

```
    $results = $rds->waitUntilDBInstanceAvailable([
        'DBInstanceIdentifier' => 'my-rds-instance'
    ]);

    $instanceEndPoint = $results->DBInstances->EndPoint // Theoretically
```

Comment: Did you have any particular question about it?

Comment: I was unable to use waitUntilDBInstanceAvailable the same way waiters are used in aws documentation. I want to access my Endpoint Address once the instance is up. I ended up just creating a while loop and hitting describeDBInstances until it tells me that my RDS instance is available.

Answer (score 1):

Waiters share the input parameters of the operation they use. In this case, the docs say "The input array uses the parameters of the DescribeDBInstances operation", which means you can use the parameters of the [DescribeDBInstances operation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Rds.RdsClient.html#_describeDBInstances).

However, waiters do not return results as you have assumed in your code example. Looking at the docs, there is no return value documented. Therefore, the usage of waiters is consistent with the documentation. If you need to get data about the thing you are waiting for, then you need to follow up with a separate call after the waiting is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your exact question, but check this question/answer:

[Is it possible to register a callback function to waitUntilDBInstanceAvailable()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847639/is-it-possible-to-register-a-callback-function-to-waituntildbinstanceavailable)